# Programmatically set color of Box2D body's sprite or image

Tags: box2d, cocos2d, color, ccsprite

In my basic Cocos2D + Box2D iPhone app I have a bunch of circular Box2D bodies.  I'd like to change the color of the circles programatically.  **What's the easiest way to do this?**

So far I'm just assigning a CCSprite* to the b2body->userData.  So perhaps I can change the colors in my sprite sheet programmatically?  Seems like there's an easier way.  I'm just not sure what it is.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cocos2d CCSprites have a three byte color property](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite.html#ab7c1fe8d2419d19873095f2070d758f5). You can use it like `sprite.color = ccc3(r, g, b)`.